# CJK Package to Type Bolded Japanese Texts

Tags: fonts, bold, cjk, japanese

I want to produce a few Japanese sentences using CJK package. Also, I want to make some words bolded. Simply, I tried the following, but obviously, it does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\textbf{こんにちわ}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

What would be the easiest way to bold some Japanese texts using CJK package?

Comment: What do you mean by "obviously it doesn't work"? I have no idea what it says and if it is japanese but I get an output and it is bold.

Answer (score 7):

To long for a comment. I have no problem with your code (compiled with texlive 2018):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\textbf{こんにちわ} こんにちわ
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With miktex it doesn't work. Miktex is missing some files. You would need to install them manually.

Comment: +1 for your answer. I have delete mine.